Vertical arrow between supra and subindex
I want to represent a Map $T$ between two objects, I use supra and sub-index to show the initial and final object. For example, $T^r_s$ represents a map from $r$ to $s$. Since it is easy to forget the convention of which one is the initial object I want to add a vertical arrow from the supra to the subindex. How can I do that?

Why not consider a pre-/post superscript (image)?

It could work but still be confusing in some scenarios. For example, if I assume the convention is in reading direction then your symbol would read r to s. But if I try to compose maps it would read s to r since composition goes in an anti-reading direction. Like $sTu /circ rTs$ would be very hard to read.

I'm not sure what the purpose is. State a convention and follow it, it's much simpler.
Anyway…
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\map}[3]{% #1 = map name, #2 = source, #3 = target
  #1\vcenter{\offinterlineskip\ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
    $\scriptstyle #2$\cr
    \noalign{\vskip1pt}
    \scalebox{0.5}{$\scriptstyle\downarrow$}\cr
    \noalign{\vskip1pt}
    $\scriptstyle #3$\cr
  }}%
}

\begin{document}

$\map{T}{r}{s}$\quad
$\map{U}{s}{t}\circ\map{T}{r}{s}=\map{V}{r}{t}$

\end{document}



If I can put all the information needed in the symbol at the cost of an extra little arrow, I think it's worth it. It is a simple aid to remember the convention and makes it clear even without the need to search in the notes if I am using the sub or supra index as the source.
In any case, I aimed for a simple question with a concrete answer that you indeed provided. Thank you for that part.

I did it myself with chatgpt's help of course.
Vanilla command
    $T \underset{s}{\overset{r}{\downarrow}}$

If you want the super and subscript to be smaller so it does get outside the line you can scale them using Scalebox
    $ T\scalebox{0.7}{$\underset{s}{\overset{r}{\downarrow}}$} $

If you just want the \downarrow to be smaller use
    $ T\underset{s}{\overset{r}{\scalebox{0.5}{$\downarrow$}}} $

